# How can I coerce this type to recognize that subtype constraints match?

Tags: typescript

The interface declarations below result in the following error:

```
Interface 'ItemI<T, P>' incorrectly extends interface 'P'.
  'ItemI<T, P>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'P', but 'P' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '_ItemFundamentI<T>'.
```

```js
export interface ItemBuildI<T> {
    readonly name : string, 
    readonly props : T,
}

export interface _ItemFundamentI<T> extends ItemBuildI<T> {
    readonly __typename__ : typeof ITEM_TYPENAME,
    readonly __itemTypename__ : string,
    readonly key : string,
    readonly createdAt : Date,
    readonly modifiedAt : Date,
    readonly context : string | undefined,
}

export interface ItemI<T, P extends _ItemFundamentI<T>> extends P, _ItemFundamentI<T> {

}
```

While I understand what this message is saying, I'm confused as to why `P extends _ItemFundamentI<T>` is not recognized as an object which `extends _ItemFundamentI<T>`. Is it because I could potentially overwrite the values in an extension?

If so, how best can I coerce this type recognition? Is there way I can protect certain object keys from future overwrites?

Comment: What are you trying to do with your `ItemI` interface there? It doesn't make sense that you take `T` to extend from `_ItemFundament<T>` but also `P` has to extend `_ItemFundament<T>` so just extending from `P` should be sufficient (although still fails). Am I missing something?

Comment: You can't have an interface extend a generic type parameter... anything that looks like `interface Foo<T> extends T` will fail.  Personally I think the error message here is a bit buggy as it mentions "the interface `P`" but the fact that there's an error is completely to be expected.   As for what you're trying to do, I don't exactly understand it... often things that look like `interface Foo<T> extends T {...}` could be rewritten as `type Foo<T> = T & {...}` but this depends on the use case and there's not enough of a [mcve] here for me to know.

Comment: Nope, you're not missing anything. P is should be sufficient, but it still fails. I was attempting to coerce with the second extension arg. Didn't work obviously.

Comment: @jcalz I kept running into statically know vs. unknown issues when trying to use intersections in this particular case.

In short, I was messing around with simulating inheritance in a couple different ways. I can, of course, use extends more conventionally. But, I liked the way the Child<Type, Parent> read for a particular API.